# Зачем нужен метод .filter() в jQuery?

Tags: jquery

В секции «[Refining & Filtering Selections](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/#refining-amp-filtering-selections)» страницы «[Selecting Elements](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)», есть следующий пример:

```
$( "ul li" ).filter( ".current" ); // unordered list items with class of current
```

Зачем использовать `.filter()`, то есть почему бы просто сразу не выбрать пункты списка с классом `.current`:

```
$( "ul li.current" );
```

Comment: в нативном JS такой метод тоже есть, если что [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: скорее уж `$( "ul li.current" );` а так я думаю, это просто еще один из механизмов выбора. например,у вас есть уже набор элементов, а вы хотите его уточнить. а впрочем гуру может чего более правильного скажут

Comment: @lexxl, ага, просто не пользовался таким. @splash58, да: `$( "ul li.current" );` — невнимательность моя.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Помимо фильтрации по селектору, есть более важная особенность: можно задать функцию, на основе которой произойдет какое-либо действие.
Выглядит это так:

`.filter(function(index))` - она фильтрует набор элементов c помощью заданной функции. Эта функция вызывается отдельно, для каждого из выбранных элементов. Если она возвращает `true`, то текущий элемент будет включен в конечный результат. Сами элементы доступны в функции, в переменной `this`, а их порядковые номера в наборе — в переменной `index`.

Например `$("div").filter(filterDivs)`  вернет `div`-элементы, "одобренные" функцией `filterDivs`.

Пример (находим и отмечаем элементы списка, которые имеют один элемент заключенный в тег  (жирное начертание)):

```js
 $('li').filter(function(index){
    return $('strong', this).length == 1;
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

```css
ul{list-style-type:none; padding-left:20px}
li{padding:2px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <strong>элемент</strong> номер 1
  </li>
  <li>элемент номер 2</li>
  <li>элемент номер 3</li>
  <li>
    <strong>элемент</strong> номер <strong>4</strong>
  </li>
  <li>элемент номер 5</li>
  <li>элемент номер 6</li>
</ul>
```

Можете задавать функции для фильтрации любой сложности, писать любые условия.
Скорее как раз для таких случаев лучше применять фильтр